# Increase float certain time period?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, floating-point, increment

I am trying to create a somewhat easy of a method for my game however I am not quite sure how to implement it. I have a float right now that starts at .1, I would like it to increment to 1 in a certain time frame.

Lets say this time frame was .5 seconds. Now clearly this method would be called on an update loop to increase it every time however I am not sure where to begin.

I hate to post a question without any code but I just don't know the logistics of it. Would I divide the result number by the deltaTime? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand your difficulty, just use an NSTimer.

Comment: logistics != logic ;) logistics is transporting wares, where they need to go and when they have to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this float is a property of a CCNode descendant, try CCActionTween : here is the excerpt from the docs (version 2.1):

```
 /** CCActionTween

 CCActionTween is an action that lets you update any property of an object.
 For example, if you want to modify the "width" property of a target from 200 to 300 in 2     
 seconds, then:

 id modifyWidth = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:2 key:@"width" from:200 to:300];
 [target runAction:modifyWidth];

 Another example: CCScaleTo action could be rewriten using CCPropertyAction: (sic) CCActionTween

// scaleA and scaleB are equivalents
 id scaleA = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:2 scale:3];
 id scaleB = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:2 key:@"scale" from:1 to:3];

 @since v0.99.2
 */
```

EDIT :

Example : say you have a Cannon class, which derives from CCNode (as in the .h below)

```
@interface Cannon:CCNode {

    float _bulletInitialVelocity;
    float _firingRate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float bulletInitialVelocity;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float firingRate;
@end

in the cannon logic, you could

CCTweenAction *fr = [CCTweenAction actionWithDuration:60.0 key:@"firingRate" from:.25 to:.75];
[self runAction:fr];
```

this could increase the firing rate over a period of 60 seconds. You could do the same for bullet's initial velocity. Notice these properties are not CCNode properties, but some you created yourself by extending CCNode. I wrote it old style so you can see that the properties are actually 'backed' by an iVar.

Comment: It is not a CCNode descendant. Its just a regular float I am using for other purposes. But what I am looking for is exactly what you posted. I am just looking to find a way to do this outside of Cocos2D.

Comment: I meant if the float is in the scope (an iVar) within a CCNode descendant ... just checking we are on same page. If not, why tag it cocos2d ?

Comment: I tagged it cocos2d because I was curious if Cocos2D already had something built in to support this. I am still confused though, how would CCActionTween work on a float ivar? It seems like it only works on CCActions.

Comment: @iBradApps see example above